# Print barcodes in multiple columns

Tags: javascript, printing, barcode

I have a document that  prints out the barcodes and isbn's of books, my problem is that it only prints one column on a page.  I would like to print either 2 or three columns (if the page will support that many columns) per page.  I am using javascript to generate my barcodes with book titles.  here is the code:

```
    for (x=0;x<data.isbn.length;x++)
    {
                if (x == 5){
                '<div class="page-break"></div>';
                } else 
                first += '$("#'+indexGlobal+'").barcode("'+isbn[x]+'", "codabar",{barHeight:40, fontSize:30, output:"bmp"});';
        second += '<div class="wrapper"><div id="'+indexGlobal+'"></div><div class="fullSKU">&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp '+isbn[x]+
                '</div><br/><div class="title">'+title[x]+'</div></div>&nbsp &nbsp';
        indexGlobal++;

                }
                }
            });//end of ajax call

        var barcode =  window.open('','BarcodeWindow','width=400');
        var html = '<html><head><title>Barcode</title><style type="text/css">'+
        '.page-break{display:block; page-break-before:always; }'+
        'body{width: 2in;}'+
        '.wrapper{height: 1in;margin-left:10px;margin-top:5px;margin-right:5px;}'+
        '.fullSKU{float: left;}'+
        '.shortSKU{float: right;font-size:25px;font-weight:bold;}'+
        '.title{float: left;}'+
        '</style><script type="text/javascript"src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="../barcode/jquery-barcode.js"></script><script>$(document).ready(function() {'+first+'window.print();window.close();});</script></head><body>'+second+'</body></html>';
        barcode.document.open();
        barcode.document.write(html);
        barcode.document.close();
```

Any suggestions to have this print in multiple columns?

Comment: What does the generated html look like?

Comment: it prints the bar codes with the title of the book, but just in one column down the page.  To save paper I want to be able to print in multiple columns.

Comment: That's not what I asked... what does the html source CODE look like? describing what it renders as is pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A friend of mine pointed me in the right direction.  I changed the width of the body

```
'body{width: 2in;}'+
```

to be the size of the page (10 inches since it will print landscape), and then used the css3 property of 3 column:

```
'body{width: 10in;-moz-column-count:3; -webkit-column-count:3;column-count:3;}'
```

Hope this will help someone else out.